# Нужна ли запятая или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Предложение: 
Если необходимо узнать, что лучше() вечернее или заочное обучение, то я отвечу так: все зависит от Ваших целей.

Нужен ли какой-либо знак на месте скобок? Верно ли расставлены другие знаки?

Comment: Тоже склоняюсь к :, но в предложении получается 2 двоеточия..смущает, хотя оба поставлены не просто так..

Comment: Два двоеточия вполне нормальное явление. Если же вас все же смущает два двоеточия, можно переделать предложение. Если необходимо узнать, что лучше: вечернее или заочное обучение, то я отвечу. Все зависит от Ваших целей.

Comment: Переделывать не хотелось бы...ниже предложили тире, по-моему тоже подходит?

Comment: @ЕленаИнди, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, но так и не ясно, возможно и тире, и двоеточие, или только двоеточие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А. Для отдельного предложения возможны два варианта:

(1) ЧтО лучше: вечернее или заочное обучение? (2)Что лУчше - вечернее или заочное обучение? Они различаются логическим ударением. В первом случае ударение падает на местоимение, что позволяет сделать предупредительную паузу и обозначить ее двоеточием. Семантика этих вариантов практически одинаковая.

Б. "Если необходимо узнать, что лучше - вечернее или заочное обучение, то я отвечу так: все зависит от Ваших целей".

В сложном предложении лучше применить вариант с тире, так как его интонация строится в соответствии со старшей структурой (предупредительная пауза внутри придаточного предложения не обозначается). На письме также в этом случае нет необходимости в использовании двух двоеточий.

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно.

Answer (score 0):

...что лучше: вечернее или заочное обучение, то отвечу так:

Answer (score 0):

Я бы после слова "лучше" поставил тире, которое обычно заменяет слово "а именно":
Если необходимо узнать, что лучше - вечернее или заочное обучение, то я отвечу так: все зависит от Ваших целей.

Comment: Хорошо ложится этот вариант)